# Отсортировать и вывести список пар имя-значение из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Набросал такой код

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
with open('work.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.strip():  # skip blank lines
            name, money = line.split()
            counter[name] = int(int(money)*0.25+(int(money)))

for name, money in counter.most_common():
    print(name, money)
```

Он из файла собирает данные о работниках. Вот что в файле:

```
Лужков 10000
Измайлов 11000
Васьков 13000
Дмитриев 12000
Гуськов 7000
```

Повышает на 25% значение money и выводит. Всё хорошо. но как отсортировать по алфавиту?

Comment: в сторону: `counter[name] = int(money)*5//4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, зачем вы здесь используете `Counter`. Для данных типа ключ-значение используется словарь.

```
result_dict = {}
with open('work.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.strip():
            name, money = line.split()
            result_dict[name] = int(money) * 1.25

for name, money in sorted(result_dict.items()):
    print(name, money)
```

Метод `items` возвращает представление словаря как набор кортежей `(key, value)`. Так как функция `sorted` вызывается без указания параметра сортировки, используется поведение по-умолчанию: сортировка по первому элементу кортежа - фамилии в данном случае.

Comment: Оу, доходчиво. Спасибо)